# Frame with adjustable width and height using mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic-html

I'm not sure where to ask this, so I've included the html, web, and css categories (I think it's css though I could be barking up the wrong tree). Basically I'm trying to create an html page with a header that never changes (non adjustable) but the content area consists of a left frame (or div perhaps?) that has search options and the right area is also divided into two rows to display the search results. Is CSS the way to go for what I'm trying to create? I've attached an image as reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUKdC.jpg

If CSS is the right way to go, can someone guide me on how I should start this?

Comment: Have you considered the Jquery resizable method?  You can declare a starting size/shape but make it resizable. http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a framework called jqlayout, Example http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html

You can play around with this.

Plugin page http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm

Comment: Upthumb for you too sir! Is this the route I should be going and one that you recommend? This does seem to provide everything I need. Any other alternatives out there that I should be looking up?

Comment: yes, this one suit you the most, you can adjust the frame, or freeze the frame, you can load any page into frame, even iframe can be used.
Working fine with my project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the dragging feature is impossible to achieve with plain .css you need some jquery involve. My question is, why do you need these areas to be draggable? I'm asking because maybe there is a different solution and you are stuck on this one.

Comment: Oh, is jqeury where I should be looking? I'm still designing the website on paper at the moment. What are other alternatives to jquery? Also an up thumb for you sir!